# C# not downloading

Tags: c#, file, download

I have problem with downloading files through C#.

I have a class which handles downloading like this:

```
namespace Ultra_Script
{
    class FileDownloader
    {

        private readonly string _url;
        private readonly string _fullPathWheretoSave;
        private bool _result = false;
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

        public FileDownloader(string url, string fullPathWheretoSave)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullPathWheretoSave)) throw new ArgumentNullException("fullPathWhereToSave");

            this._url = url;
            this._fullPathWheretoSave = fullPathWheretoSave;

        }

        public bool StartDownload(int timeout)
        {

            try
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_fullPathWheretoSave));

                if (File.Exists(_fullPathWheretoSave))
                {
                    File.Delete(_fullPathWheretoSave);
                }
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var ur = new Uri(_url);
                    //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
                    Console.WriteLine(@"Downloading File:");
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, _fullPathWheretoSave);
                    _semaphore.Wait(timeout);
                    return _result && File.Exists(_fullPathWheretoSave);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cant download file");
                Console.Write(e);
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                this._semaphore.Dispose();
            }

        }

        private void WebClientDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("/r   -->    {0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);
        }

        private void WebClientDownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            _result = !args.Cancelled;
            if (!_result)
            {
                Console.Write(args.Error.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Download Finished!");
            _semaphore.Release();
        }

        public static bool DownloadFile(string url, string fullPathWhereToSave, int timeoutInMilliSec)
        {
            return new FileDownloader(url, fullPathWhereToSave).StartDownload(timeoutInMilliSec);
        }

    }
}
```

And i called it like this:

```
public static void InstallBasicSW()
        {

            var succes = FileDownloader.DownloadFile("https://github.com/Corbieman/Basic_SW/raw/master/JaVa.exe", "C:\\Windows", 99999999);
            Console.WriteLine("Done - Succes: " + succes);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

But only what im getting in Console is:

> Download Finished!
>
> Done - Succes: False;

I don't get any error message or progress bar. This message just pops up instantly. And file doesn't download into that path. Anybody know or have idea where can be the problem?

Comment: Where do you set `_result` to true? And it seems like you have a lot more code than you need. I'd think you'd only need 2-3 lines to accomplish all this.

Comment: Are you sure, there is any file coming from: https://github.com/Corbieman/Basic_SW/raw/master/JaVa.exe ?

Comment: Installing something in C:\Windows? No thank you. Please learn to use the OS before installing sketchy software on it...

Comment: How can you not get either "_Downloading File:_" or "_Cant download file_" as part of your output???

Comment: @elgonzo If you don't wait for your async call to finish, you're likely not to get an exception. I imagine "Downloading File" was just omitted from the question.

Comment: @mason, i was not trying to say that i was expecting an exception output specifically, but any output including a possible exception output that -- according to the code in the question -- is a prerequisite for the other outputs OP got. The reason why i asked is because i  am not certain whether the output OP mentioned is just incomplete or whether the output stems from a code version that is different from the one shown here in the question (like a version of the code OP tinkered with before or after getting this particular output).

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey Its downloading not installing, and its only for test purposes.

Comment: Sad im getting - rep just for asking question when im beginner.

Comment: Couple of points: 1) your download is failing, but `args.Cancelled` is `false` so that's why you're not seeing the error message, 2) your progress output is missing the `$` character - `Console.Write($"/r   -->    {0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);` and 3) if you'd added a breakpoint in `WebClientDownloadCompleted` you would have seen the problems. Debug first, ask a question when you still can't find the problem.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks, finally helpfull answer :-) Gonna check it.

Comment: @stuartd is the `$` needed in that line of code?  It is calling the overload of `Console.Write` that takes a formatting paramter.  I would think the version using `$` would look like this:  `Console.Write($"/r --> {e.ProgressPercentage}%");`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway you are quite correct, I was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of method DownloadFile need the full file's path.

Try this :

```
    public static void InstallBasicSW()
    {
        var succes = FileDownloader.DownloadFile("https://github.com/Corbieman/Basic_SW/raw/master/JaVa.exe", @"C:\Temps\JaVa.exe", 99999999);
        Console.WriteLine("Done - Succes: " + succes);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Why have you this result?
I think it's because you pass a directory path instead of a file path.
The download cancel and finish immediately.

A explicit exception will be more helpful...

Comment: This is the correct answer. the actual exception is "Access to the path 'C:\Windows' is denied."

Comment: Maybe with admin right. But I prefer don't test modify this folder.

Comment: @stuartd yeah just found that out. problem is acces denied is on whole disk even on different partition, any idea what could cause that? Thanks

//EDIT: Gonna try to run it as admin for different folder

Answer (score 0):

So problem was i had to run it as admin and correct the path like you said guys. Its working now, Thanks.